# How to set default login page and after login open tabs in ionic-4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am creating ionic tabs project and I want to set in default  login page then after open tabs . I am set in default login page but after login i am not getting tabs  in ionic 4. Please help me how to resolve this problem....?

tabs.router.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'tabs/tab1', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I am changing the route but do not getting tabs plase help me how to add route to open tabs after login .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

**tabs.router.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          { path: '', loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'}
        ]
      },
      ...
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/start/tabs/tab1', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
  }
];
...
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'start', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
];
...
```

Comment: how to load tabs after login

Comment: I have three tabs tab1 , tab2 and tab3 and one main tab...@Remi sture

Answer (score 1):

**app-routing.module.ts**

...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },<--here
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
];
```

**tabs.router.module.ts**

...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',<--here
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          { path: '', loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'}
        ]
      },
      ...
      { path: 'tabs', redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1', pathMatch: 'full'}<--here
    ]
  }
];
```

...

navigate with: `this.router.navigate(['tabs']);`

Answer (score 0):

The Answer given by **B.Mind** is working fine for me. But with few **changes**.

For Angular 8 and 9, the lazy load declaration changed. Since Angular 8 introduced the new recommended module loading method, previously the default method of lazy loading modules was to specify a string path to a module:

```
{ path: 'tab1', loadChildren: 'src/app/tabs/tab1.module#Tab2PageModule' }
```

So Change it to

```
{ path: 'tab1', loadChildren: () => import('src/app/tabs/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule) }
```

and navigate like this

```
this.route.navigateByUrl('/tabs/tab1');
```