# Error when I tried to go tabs menu after login

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, ionic-framework, tabs

I has create a Ionic project with tabs and I begin to do authentification system (login/register). My problem is , I want to redirect on the tabs page menu after login. But it's don't work I have this error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'tabs/tab1'

If you want more info tell me :)
Thanks for help !

route in app-routing.module :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPage
    //loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule'}
];
```

I want that redirect on tabs page after login success.

Comment: Ok i resolve my problem with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666533/how-to-set-default-login-page-and-after-login-open-tabs-in-ionic-4 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your login.ts code?

Also inside the paths I use to add at the end: `{path: **, redirect: 'your-route'}`

So if no routes match before, you redirect the user to the page you want. In this case, tabs page.

Comment: I think you want only this : `loginUser(value){this.authService.loginUser(value)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.errorMessage = "";
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/home');
      }, err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.message;
      })`

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
{ path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule'}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data to   `path: 'dashboard'`

then pass redirect to `redirectTo: '/dashboard/login',`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: LoginPage,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', loadChildren:'./login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
            { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
            { path: 'home', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule'},
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/dashboard/login',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: White page and the error when I change url

Comment: what is the error

Comment: can you post your module

Answer (score 0):

[image: I have a white page when I use your solution wi]

I have a white page when I use your solution with no error

I have this only I put /dashboard/login in url

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type LoginPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and LoginPageModule! Please consider moving LoginPage to a higher module that imports AppModule and LoginPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes LoginPage then import that NgModule in AppModule and LoginPageModule.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `app.router.ts`

```
  const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
];
```

Inside login.ts

if you are using angular Router.

```
this.router.navigate(['/']);
```